# Skip a rails ActiveRecord validation while saving a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a function in my rails project where I am handling the situation where a record is not saved due to validation failure.

```
begin
  raise unless profile.save
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError => e
    e.message = "Warning: Some validations failed. Force Saving"
    profile.save(:validate => false)
    puts e.message
  end 
end
```

Here, to force save the `profile`, I have to skip all validations. Is there a way to skip just the particular validation that is failing here?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help You

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :method_1
  validate :method_2, :if => :do_validate?

  def do_validate?
    #return true or false based on scenerio
  end

end
```

You can have conditional validation.

Answer (score 0):

Which validation u want to skip, if suppose u want to skip `validates_presence_of` for create method, then allow only update method to check that validation

`validates_presence_of :on => :update`

hope this helps